# How can I stop a goroutine that is reading from UDP?

Tags: go, udp, goroutine

I have a go program that uses a goroutine to read UDP packets.
I wanted to use a select clause and a "stopping" channel to close the goroutine to shut down as soon as it is not needed anymore.

Here is a simple code example for the goroutine:

```
func Run(c chan string, q chan bool, conn *net.UDPConn) {

    defer close(c)

    buf := make([]byte, 1024)

    for {
        select {
            case <- q:
                return
            default:
                n, _, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(buf)
                c <- string(buf[0:n])
                fmt.Println("Received ", string(buf[0:n]))

                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The connection is created as:

```
    conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp",addr.Addr)
```

And the goroutine is supposed to terminate using:

```
    close(q)
```

After closing the "stopping" channel ("q") the goroutine does not immediately stop. I need to send one more string via the UDP connection. When doing so the goroutine stops.
I simply do not understand this behaviour and I would be grateful if somebody could enlighten me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try closing the connection?

Comment: It is advisable to close channels where you open them. The `defer` statement is made to promote that behavior (have open and close together so you do not forget to close). That might also be the influencing factor here for the behavior you are observing

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen: no, closing channels is not a cleanup action, you are not required to close them, and it is often incorrect to close them.

Comment: @JimB My remark is about opening and closing at the same location, not in two different functions. The code as presented could be confusing to read since the deferred close is not at the creation of the channel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program is likely stopped at this line when you close the channel:

```
n, _, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(buf)
```

Because execution is blocked at a `ReadFrom` method, the `select` statement is not being evaluated, therefore the close on channel `q` is not immediately detected.  When you do another send on the UDP connection, `ReadFrom` unblocks and (once that loop iteration finishes) control moves to the `select` statement: at that point the close on `q` is detected.

You can [close the connection](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn.Close) to unblock `ReadFrom`, as was suggested in a comment.  See the [PacketConn documentation in the `net` package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#PacketConn), especially **"Any blocked ReadFrom or WriteTo operations will be unblocked and return errors"**:

```
// Close closes the connection.
// Any blocked ReadFrom or WriteTo operations will be unblocked and return errors.
Close() error
```

Depending on your needs a timeout might be an option as well, see again [PacketConn documentation in the `net` package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#PacketConn):

```
 // ReadFrom reads a packet from the connection,
 // copying the payload into b. It returns the number of
 // bytes copied into b and the return address that
 // was on the packet.
 // ReadFrom can be made to time out and return
 // an Error with Timeout() == true after a fixed time limit;
 // see SetDeadline and SetReadDeadline.
 ReadFrom(b []byte) (n int, addr Addr, err error)
```